# Relationship between sums and direct sums

Tags: abstract-algebra

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Second_isomorphism_theorem_3) we have the second isomorphism theorem of $R$-modules:

> Let $M$ be a module, and let $S$ and $T$ be submodules of $M$. Then:
>
> The sum $S+T=\{s+t|s\in S,t\in T\}$ is a submodule of M,
>        The intersection $S \cap T$ is a submodule of $S$, and
>
> The quotient modules $(S + T) / T$ and $S / (S \cap T)$ are
>   isomorphic.

Can I change the operation $+$ for the direct sum $\oplus$?

In fact, what's the relation between sum and direct sums?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Direct sum is a sum in which there is no intersection in the sense that $S\cap T= \{0\}$.. In the case of $(S+T)/T$ being isomorphic to $S/(S\cap T)$ the sum is not direct.. for suppose it is they would have written Just $(S+T)/T\cong S$ Instead of $(S+T)/T\cong S/(S\cap T)$ because $S\cap T$ would not play much role...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik thanks, very helpful

Comment: you are welcome!